# Create a Debian package for my Django application

Tags: python, django, package, debian

I have a python Django project that runs on my local by running manage.py. It also runs fine on a debian machine when I  do a scp of my project from my local to the server . After installing the requirement.txt , works as expected. But, I wanted to know  if there is a way I can package my Django that can be easy installed on a debian machine .

Thanks,
Archana

Comment: I think you'd want to check out https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Comment: So does this work on debian machines as well.

Comment: I don't really understand why would you want to package a Django project as a `.deb`, seems like a bad idea. I'd advise you to look more into cookiecutter because I think that would provide a solution for what you want to accomplish. You'll be able to `pip install` your project on any machine afterwards.

Comment: @Alex Ok will try that . :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there are some packaging guidelines. It may like a lot of work at first glance to you, but it's worth to read at least the maintainer guide, to get an overview. The packaging tutorial covers a lot of questions you may have. The Debian Python team as put together some pages, that also should deliver answers to most of your questions, there is also some python related Packaging guidelines, that may come handy later.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf

https://wiki.debian.org/Python

Second there is the debian-mentors irc channel where you can ask questions its #debian-mentors on oftc network (you can use it via https://webchat.oftc.net/ ), keep in mind that it can take a while until people answer in irc, just say hello, ask your question and wait. Same goes for the #debian-python where its likely to find a dev who has packaged a django app before

Third take any package that has the same approach as the things you want to make and unpack including the devscripts:

```
 mkdir /tmp/mydeb && cd /tmp/mydeb && apt-get source hello
```

replace "hello" with the name of any already nicely packaged django app, in /tmp/mydeb/hello-xyz/debian/ (where xzy is the current version of the software) you'll find the files needed for packing that can be used as inspiration.

Also the internet says: https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/hello-world/ (haven't tried it, but on first glance it looks like it may work)